# phpunit / excluded files still returning warnings

Tags: php, phpunit

using version 8.1.6, and Given the following phpunit.xml :

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="SlimSkeleton">
      <directory>tests</directory>
      <exclude>./tests/Functional/BaseTestCase.php</exclude>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

And the following directory structure :

- `./tests/Functional/serviceA/...`
- `./tests/Functional/BaseTestCase.php`

I keep getting the following output :

```
...
1) Warning
No tests found in class "Tests\Functional\BaseTestCase".
...
```

I run the suitr via a scripts command in composer.json :

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
       "test": "phpunit"
      }
}
```

Is it expected ? Is there a way to silence this warning ?

Comment: what is exactly the PHP Unit version you use?

Comment: @Jimmix added in the original post (8.1.6)

Comment: in which part of the dir struct is localed the file `phpunit.xml`? have you tried also with   `<directory>./tests</directory>` ?

Comment: At the dame level as the tests folder

Comment: How do you invoke the test-runner? How do you ensure you execute *that* testsuite? - maybe exclude works for directory paths only?

Comment: Have you tried making `BaseTestCase` an `abstract` class?

Comment: @hakre i've added the info about how i run. I just want to know whats the way to exclude a file from the runner, is that so hard ? Isnt there a single way to do it correctly?

Comment: @ceejayoz how would you do so ? Is doing so solves the problem ? I'm so surprised to receive question - it sounds like there's no identified way to do i correctly

Comment: @Ben You just add `abstract` to the class definition. See Laravel's, for example: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php

Comment: @Ben: Just checked in a different test-suite w/ `<exclude>`: It does not operate on file-path but only on directory-path. Also it can not be the same path as the `<dicretory>` entry. HTH. /e: And well this was hard for me back in 2011: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5934347/367456 - I think this is also similar to what @ceejayoz pointed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpunit by default finds `*Test.php`, so even without `<exclude>` in phpunit.xml it would ignore BaseTestCase.php by running `composer test`.

> Using tests instead of tests/EmailTest would instruct the PHPUnit command-line test runner to execute all tests found declared in *Test.php sourcecode files in the tests directory.

https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html

I see "No tests found" warning if I specify command-line argument like the below. But this is not the intended usage of [BaseTestCase.php from Slim-Skelton](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton/blob/master/tests/Functional/BaseTestCase.php).

```
$ composer test tests/Functional/BaseTestCase.php
> phpunit 'tests/Functional/BaseTestCase.php'
PHPUnit 8.1.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

W                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 21 ms, Memory: 4.00 MB

There was 1 warning:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "Tests\Functional\BaseTestCase".

WARNINGS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Warnings: 1.
```